# How to Force Menu to Behind Triangle Border

Tags: html, css

[image]

As a picture above, There are horizontal menu, and the below is carousel slider. I want to make horizontal menu behind to triangle border.

I've done with:

- force with `margin-top:-10px` to make carousel overriding the horizontal menu.

The result is like this:

[image]

I play with `z-index` but it's not worked.
Here is the code:

```css
/* MENU */

.menu {
 display:block;
 padding:0 10px;
}

.border-segitiga {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 8px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-image: url(../images/dotted.png) 14 13 13 repeat round;
 -webkit-border-image: url(../images/dotted.png) 14 13 13 repeat round;
 -o-border-image: url(../images/dotted.png) 14 13 13 repeat round;
 border-image: url(../images/dotted.png) 14 13 13 repeat round;
 z-index:5;
 margin-top:-12px;
}

nav {
 display:inline-block;
}

nav li {
 display:inline;
 list-style:none;
 font-family:"DINCond-Regular", arial;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

nav li:after {
 content:"";
 border-right:1px solid #4fb36b;
 padding-right:15px;
 position:relative;
 bottom:3px;
}

nav li:last-child:after {
 border:0;
}

nav li a {
 color:#000;
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:24px;
 line-height:34px;
 padding:12px;
}

nav li a:hover {
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:24px;
 line-height:24px;
 background:#ffde00;
 padding:12px;
}

.active {
 background:#ffde00;
 z-index:1;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="menu">
  <nav>
   <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Beranda</a></li>
   <li><a href="berita.html">Berita</a></li>
   <li><a href="profil.html">Profil &amp; Kisah Sukses</a></li>
   <li><a href="regulasi.html">Regulasi</a></li>
   <li><a href="galeri.html">Galeri Foto</a></li>
   <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>
  </nav>
  <div class="search search-header">
   <form action="#" id="search_box">
    <input type="text" value="SEARCH" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='SEARCH'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'SEARCH':this.value;">
    <button type="submit" class="search-button"><img src="images/luv.png" title="Search" /></button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
<div class="wrapper grey border-segitiga">
 <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
  slide content
 </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do it.
Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: Please, post your completed code instead of image.

Comment: Agree! A Plunkr would be even better!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you  indexing. This code would put the triangle class on top, so to speak, indexed over the menu class.

```
  <div class="menu"><div class="triangle"></div></div>
```

Without any code it is hard to get an idea but using div in this way would put the inner div on top or first in the index of things.